# Is it possible to call the create function of another method from a the write method of a model in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

I have two models, i need to create record in demo2 model from demo model. Is it possible to access the create method of demo2 from write method of demo model?

```
class demo(models.Model):
       _name= 'demo'

       @api.multi
       def write(self,vals):
          self.env['demo2'].create({})
          return super(demo, self).write(vals)

class demo2(models.Model):
       _name = 'demo2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it's possible, there is no as such constrain , just remember one thing :

> **write** always return **True/False** and **create** **object** in 8/9 and **id** in
>   odoo7